AWS Otel exporter fails to reach OpenSearch ingestion pipeline
I had a working otel with aws-otel-collector and opensearch ingestion pipeline for a year. I stopped the pipeline, after a few days, started it again.
I now see the following error:
{
 "service": "otel-collector", 
 "kind": "exporter", 
 "data_type": "logs", 
 "name": "otlphttp", "error": "Permanent error: error exporting items, request to https://<otel-log-pipeline>:443/v1/logs responded with HTTP Status Code 401", 
 "dropped_items": 1}

My OpenSearch logs have [armeria-common-worker-epoll-3-3] ERROR com.amazon.osis.HttpAuthorization - Authentication status: 401.
I did not change anything else. could not find much information from docs. has anyone seen something similar before? why does this happen and how to fix this?
